# Multiple collections in single SOLR instance

Tags: solr

I'm using SOLR 4.0. I need to make 4 different indexes for searching, let's say, first is a list of students in a university, second is a list of products being sold on an online marketplace and so on. What I mean here is that they all hold completely different types of data.

Currently I'm running 4 instances of solr on 4 different ports each having a single collection serving one type of data. The problem is that running 4 instances of solr takes up a lot of memory space.

How can I run all 4 collections in a single solr instance? While searching, maybe I can specify in the url the collection that I'm interested in.

Comment: use one core for each

Comment: how do I configure multiple cores in a single instance? Can you provide the set of steps I need to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple cores within a single Solr instance. There is a `CoreAdmin API` for such purposes.

It has a `CREATE` action which creates a new core and registers it. Here is the sample create core request:

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=coreX&instanceDir=path/to/dir&config=config_file_name.xml&dataDir=data

Bear in mind that CREATE call must be able to find a configuration, or it will not succeed.

You can read documentation from here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-CREATE

Comment: Got it! I just had to add 4 folders for 4 different collections in solr/example/solr directory and change the name of these collections in the respective core.properties files. It works like a charm with minimal memory usage.